# @yield property without using framework laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**Can I use @yield property in php code without using framework laravel ?**

Comment: You should look into "include" or "require" http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Or even Ajax or a modern JS framework to really go the distance.

Comment: Be clear in what you want to ask. The title of the question and the description are totally unrelated.

Comment: Why are you expecting to be able to use a framework function without the framework?

Comment: @Adam I know that I can use"include" or "require" to do. but when is I use  "include" or "require" in my code I will divide file php into several files php  and this does not suit me in my project.

Comment: @NandanDesai why my question totally unrelated?

Comment: @MartinBean I do not want to use the framework in my project but I want use way or function as "yield"  because it simplifies the code and makes it easy to review it and modify it after a period of time.

Comment: @khaledDebuch Do you know what else simplifies code and makes it easy to review and modify? Using the framework instead of rebuilding the methods it offers.

Comment: May I just say this: Using a framework and avoiding using its tools is..................................................................................................... you get the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first picture explains how used @yield method in Laravel .. And the second picture explains how i can way as @yield method inside php page without use freamwork laravel.

First Image:
[image: @yield method in Laravel]

Second Image:
[image: @yield method inside php page without use freamwork laravel]

Comment: pretty guud my friend

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use blade (the templating engine that includes the @yield method), you can. There are some standalone implementations that doesn't require the laravel Framework.

If you only need the @yield property, you can relate to @Adam comment and start looking into php standard functions [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).